# Is it possible to jump into spring source code while i`m coding in IDE?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

while I`m coding java in IDEA,then i create a Collection,i could just ctrl+click to see the implimentation that how java itself implment Collection,so i can read it and try to understand its concept.
[image]

[image][image]

I can jump into Collection source code and its implmention ,But fail to see the getBean method implimentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just click the botton will see the implimentation
[image]

[image]